# ie7 pushing down floats

Tags: html, css, css-float, internet-explorer-7

I'm having an ie7 issue. Everything seem to be working fine in Firefox and IE8.

In ie7 the first element works fine but all other are push down like they have a clear applied.

image depicts this best.

[image]

Here's the code.

```
.newLabellg 
{
    float:left; 
    width:66px; 
    margin:3px 0 0 0;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000;
}


<div style="float:left; width:320px;">

    <div style="margin-bottom:10px; float:left;">
        <div class="newLabellg">Cusotmer#:</div>
        <div style="float:left;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerNumber" runat="server" Width="220px"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-bottom:10px; float:left; clear:both;">
        <div class="newLabellg">Cusotmer:</div>
        <div style="float:left;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerName" runat="server" Width="220px"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-bottom:10px; float:left; clear:both;">
        <div class="newLabellg" style="float:left;">Address:</div>
        <div style="float:left;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="Address" runat="server" Width="220px"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-bottom:10px; float:left; clear:both;">
        <div class="newLabellg">Mailing Address:</div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Address2" runat="server" Width="220px"></asp:TextBox>
        <div style="float:left; margin:3px 0 0 0">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="City" runat="server" Width="109px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="Province" runat="server" Width="109px">
        </asp:DropDownList></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Any Idea why/what ie7 is doing and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply removing `clear: both` from each instance of:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:10px; float:left; clear:both;">
```

made it look correct in the browsers I tested it with: IE7/8 + Firefox.

If removing `clear: both` causes a different problem, let us know and we can find a workaround.

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you. But just so I'm clear. The clear:both should only apply to that element and not its children? This is in fact an ie7 bug, right?

Comment: @Adam: The link in @Julian's answer confirms that it's an IE7 bug of some variety - *"IE7-/Win: Problems with float + clear on the same element"*.

Comment: Thanks That did the trick. Strange I've never run into this problem before.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say the only logical conclusion is that the `clear:both` is causing problems - because it's the only style the first item doesn't have.

`float` + `clear` on the same element causes unusual anomalies within IE7.

http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEWfc3.html